# Force Win7 to boot into specific monitor setup

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have 5 Monitors on my Win7 Pro (service pac 1) (32 bit) machine.

When I reboot it, if the monitors are off, it will do a hardware detection and create a new arrangement of monitors placing them differently then I want and also rearrange all my Icons.

Is there a way to force windows to...

1. not do a monitor detection at all and simply use what's in the registry, or
2. go ahead and do the hardware test, but ignore it and use what's in the registry?

Failing that, is there a third party utility I can use to rearrange the monitors after booting (and also restore all my icons after Windows hoses them.)

Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is especially acute for DisplayPort which acts as
a PNP device, so needs to be detected continuously and asked for its
[EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data)
which identifies the monitor.

One solution to avoid the need for detection is to set up a static EDID.

A solution for NVIDIA cards is detailed in
[Managing a Display EDID on windows](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3569/%7E/managing-a-display-edid-on-windows)
by setting the monitor to use EDID information from a file instead of
from the monitor, so auto-detect is in effect dis-activated.

Another method uses the old and free utility for setting up the EDID
is the
[Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU).

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I am looking for, thanks @harrymc. I will head down those paths and report back here. Specifically, I have a 4 port DVI video board (I think it is NVIDIA) 3 of which have DVI to VGA adapters to older monitors, one to my primary DVI monitor. The 5th uses the stock VGA port on the motherboard. Recently I was forced to replace the only DVI monitor (an LG,) with a similar DVI monitor, (an older LG) then this started happening (actually, it was a bit random before.)

Comment: My bad, it is an ATI FirePro 2450, not NVIDIA. Maybe ATI has a similar utility or maybe I can hack something up using the NVIDIA routines.

Comment: I would try CRU.